# Use SSL Certificate in ASP.NET Core 2.1 while Developing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

On an ASP.NET Core 2.1 I application appSettings file I have the following:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Certificates": {
    "Default": {
      "Path": "localhost.pfx",
      "Password": "1234"
    }
  }
}
```

I created the certificate using the dotnet command:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep "localhost.pfx" -p 1234
```

And I copied the localhost.pfx file to the project root along the appSettings file.

When I run the project on http://localhost:5000 it is redirected to https://localhost:5001.

However, I receive the browser error saying the connection is not safe and asking me to add an exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried Firefox and Google Chrome

Comment: Have you tried with the `--trust` flag in the `dev-certs` command? `dotnet dev-certs https -ep "localhost.pfx" -p 1234 --trust`.

Comment: In order to actually be trusted, the self-signed cert has to be added to the trust cert store in Windows (which is what the `--trust` argument achieves), but you can also just do so manually. However, this only affects browsers that rely on the Windows trusted certificate store, which as far as I'm aware is only IE, Edge, and Chrome. Firefox, in particular, does not, so you still have to add a manual exception in Firefox.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Include the `--trust` option.

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep "localhost.pfx" -p 1234 --trust
```

That creates a certificate that will work with these appsettings.json:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Certificates": {
    "Default": {
      "Path": "localhost.pfx",
      "Password": "12345"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Notes

If you need to recreate the certificate, clean the certificate store first.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

The `--trust` option will work right away with Chrome; with Firefox, though, we will still need to add a security exception.

Using `--trust` means that we no longer need to add the `"Kestrel"` section to the appsettings.json file.

Comment: With the option you suggest is still necessary to add the certificate to project path and add the kestrel part to the settings? I am asking this because I thought that using a local certificate file, e.g. on Project root, than adding it to the store would not be necessary.

Comment: No. With the `--trust` flag, it isn't necessary to add the custom kestrel settings to appsettings.json.

Comment: What about SSL for production using a NON-self signed certificate?

Comment: @Wes I suggest opening another StackOverflow question for that.